# Facebook comment like box and share button mysteriously disappeared

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I use facebook like box comments box and share button on my website. There was no problem and i did nothing that can affect the codes. However they began to disappeare and then come back.

I load the page and there is no facebook plug in.After some reloading they appear on the page.

I am not sure if i told my problem clearly, but indeed i already can not understand the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Either it's a facebook issue , or your internet connection since the javascript SDK is not being loaded sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I experienced the problem with other different machines so I guess it is not about my connection.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that facebook didn't make a change.
Double check that it's not a css/style issue.

Try running a HTTP request analyzer (HTTPFox or Wireshark) and make sure the request to facebook are being completed.

Comment: I used fiddler and check the requests. Its so strange that when I load te page I see requests from facebook and I also see the like button and others. After refreshing I can not see any facebook request and like button and others disappeared. After two and three refreshing they all came back.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked properly before, most of the these are facbook issues where javascript sdk not loading etc etc. Some times they become normal after some time (say 1 hour or even less)

Comment: I was thinking the same but I am having this problem for 3-4 days